# Russian Characters encoding trouble

Tags: php, mysql, html, character-encoding, cyrillic

I have been working with Transferable Type and MySQL (in Russian, UTF-8 encoding - is the encoding of my database).
This is link http://ru.fxdailyinfo.com/. And testing here http://ru.fxdailyinfo.com/test.php.

My problem is in russian content output rendering. If I store 'привет босс' [Hello boss!] in mysql database it stored as 'ÐŸÑ€Ð¸Ð²ÐµÑ‚ Boss!'.

```
 [Quried result:: contents from mysql database:ÐŸÑ€Ð¸Ð²ÐµÑ‚ Boss!]

<!DOCTYPE HTML>
    <html lang='ru' dir='ltr' id="web_page" class='ru'>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    </head>
    <body>ÐŸÑ€Ð¸Ð²ÐµÑ‚ Boss!</body>
```

My expected output is

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
    <html lang='ru' dir='ltr' id="web_page" class='ru'>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    </head>
    <body>привет босс!</body>
```

I am 90% sure this problem is not rendered in MySQL server. However MySQL Info

```
character_set_client    utf8
character_set_connection    utf8
character_set_database  utf8
character_set_filesystem    binary
character_set_results   utf8
character_set_server    utf8
character_set_system    utf8
character_sets_dir  /usr/share/percona-server/charsets/
collation_connection    utf8_general_ci
collation_database  utf8_unicode_ci
collation_server    utf8_unicode_ci
completion_type NO_CHAIN
concurrent_insert   AUTO
connect_timeout 20
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: could you provide fragment of php code where you insert your data? and screenshot of phpMyAdmin browse that data `привет босс` is in table? and php code that outputs this page could be helpful either.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After you connect to your database, try sending it this (assuming $dbc is the result of mysqli_connect):

```
mysqli_query($dbc,"SET NAMES 'utf8'");
```

You can also check the output of `SHOW CREATE TABLE <your-table>;` and make sure the CHARACTER SET for the relevant columns are utf8_unicode or something that allows extended characters.